# Buffer overflow experiment: shell code executed but got "failed to read 0 bytes" error

Tags: buffer-overflow, ubuntu, shellcode

I've doing a buffer overflow experiment on a Ubuntu 16.04 VM (`Linux ubuntu 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`) and got a puzzling error after getting the shell code executed. The shell code is copied from [this tutorial](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/writing-64-bit-shellcode-part-2-removing-null-bytes-0161591/) and is specifically `"\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x31\xd2\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x11\x48\xc1\xe3\x08\x48\xc1\xeb\x08\x53\x48\xc7\xc0\x3b\x11\x11\x11\x48\x89\xe7\x48\xc1\xe0\x38\x48\xc1\xe8\x38\x0f\x05"`. In [edb](https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger), I see `RIP` jumps to the shell code and executes it, as shown below:

[edb showing shell code executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKowi.png)

After the `syscall` command which is supposed to `execve` shell, however, it seems to fall into a black hole. Edb starts to blank out, as shown below:

[edb blanks out after syscall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMkKJ.png)

,and as I step over in the debugger "in the dark", its command line window starts to show the following errors:

[errors in edb cli window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTuAe.png)

Wonder if anyone has seen this before and know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to do this with GDB? I think you need to configure your debugger to "follow child". I see that EDB has an open issue about this, so for now I don't think you can do this with EDB. See: https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger/issues/659. I would say try the tutorial in GDB and don't forget about `set follow-fork-mode child`